# Angularjs multiple functions

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 2 buttons:

- One scans a QR code and returns the values which works.
- Another  on the same page that confirms the input values, but I cannot get the second function to fire.

I have 2 inputs, `deviceid` and `companyid`, and 2 buttons. The scan button, via `ng-click`, calls `scanQR` and the second button, also via ng-click, calls `checkBlanks`.

A confirm ID button calls a functions to firstly check for blanks then alert the user if the input data is missing. Once the 2 inputs have content it will save the data via the `verifyDetails()` call. But I cannot get the `checkBlanks` function to run.

HTML Code is:-

```
    <ion-view title="Settings">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input" name="deviceid">
        <span class="input-label">Device ID</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="deviceid">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input" name="companyid">
        <span class="input-label">Company ID</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="companyid">
      </label>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="scanQR()" class="button button-positive button-block">Scan QR to Configure</button>
    <button ng-click="checkBlanks()" class="button button-positive button-block">Confirm ID</button>
    <form class="list">
      <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-positive" ng-checked="true">Vibrate</ion-toggle>
      <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-positive">Light on Scan</ion-toggle>
      <div style="text-align:center;" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
        <p style="color:#000000;font-size:10px;">On Android devices set to off and use the volume controls to turn the flashlight on or off.</p>
      </div>
      <ion-radio ng-model="radioCheck" value="security">Security</ion-radio>
      <ion-radio value="utilities">Utilities</ion-radio>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

AngularJS is:-

```
function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.radioCheck = "security";
  $scope.scanQR = function() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function(result) {
        var TagResponse = result.text;
        var config = TagResponse.indexOf("Config:");
        if (TagResponse !== '') {
          if (config === 0) {
            var ConfigVals = TagResponse.split(':');
            $scope.deviceid = ConfigVals[1];
            $scope.companyid = ConfigVals[2];
            $scope.$apply();
          }
        }
      });
  };
  $scope.checkBlanks = function() {
    alert("Device ID" + $scope.deviceid);
    console.log("Device ID" + $scope.device)
    if ($scope.deviceid === '') {
      alert("Please enter a device ID", Dismissed, "Error");
    } else if ($scope.companyid === '') {
      alert("Please enter a Company ID", Dismissed, "Error");
    } else {
      verifyDetails();
    }
  };
}
```

Any help appreciated, I'm very new to Angularjs and Ionic.

Comment: Start by indenting your code properly. It's unreadable that way.

Comment: You should show the HTML code as well

Comment: HTML Code added. As I'm using Ionic Creator, the HTML code is generated by Creator so I haven't changed anything.

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question. I was missing the closing () after the checkBlanks call.

Comment: OK, the function is being called, but I'm getting an undefined errors on the alert statement. I cannot get the function to check for blanks.